# Why use '\\n' rather than '\n'?

Tags: python-3.x, newline

I saw this in a Python 3 tutorial about how to download a file and this is what it kinda looks like.

```
from urllib import request
import requests


goog="http://realchart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csvs=GOOG&d=8&e=7&f=2016&g=d&a=7&b=19&c=2004&ignore=.csv"
rp=request.urlopen(goog)
s=rp.read()

cp=str(s)
m=cp.split('\\n')
dest='goog.csv'
fw=open(dest,'w')
    for c in m:
      fw.write(c+ '\n')

fw.close()
fr=open('goog.csv','r')
k=fr.read()
print(k)
```

Why was this used?

```
split('\\n')
```

Its true that the code only works properly when you use the double backslashes but why?

Comment: Maybe because the file contains an actual backslash followed by an actual letter `n`? Have you checked the contents of `cp`?

Comment: Yes it contains an actual backslash followed by `n` but then what exactly does the double backslash do ?

Comment: check my edited answer, I've added a code-snippet. The special character must be escaped, it's already answered by me and joaquim. If you don't put the first "\", the function will not search a "string", it will search a special character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The backslash is a special character inside strings, its purpose is to introduce special characters into the strings, special characters that can't otherwise be written on a keyboard in a natural way, if at all. The most common being the newline `'\n'`.

However, since the backslash is special, how do one make a string contain an actual backslash? Simple: Use the backslash to escape itself! A double-backslash will be translated into a literal backslash.

In the context of this question, the text being searched contains a literal backslash, so to find this literal backslash one must use the double backslash.

Answer (score -1):

```html
<button onclick='window.alert("\n")'>alert not escaped</button>
<button onclick='window.alert("\\n")'>alert escaped</button>
```

In a string a single backslash is a so-called 'escape' character. This is used to include special characters like tab (\t) or a new line (\n).